# VBA Sqr function and Double assignment return overflows - Mac/M1 issue?

Tags: vba

I have the following macro that works properly expect of the sqr function that returns an `overflow` error:

```
Sub BasicCalculations():

    Dim x
    Dim y
    
    x = 15
    y = 5

    '+ Add
    Debug.Print "Add: "; x + y
    
    '- Subtract
    Debug.Print "Subtract: "; x - y
    
    '-X Negation
    Debug.Print "Negate y: "; -y
    
    '* Multiplication
    Debug.Print "Multiply: "; x * y
    
    '\ Integer Division
    Debug.Print "Integer Division "; x \ y
    
    'Mod Modulus
    Debug.Print "Mod "; y Mod x
    
    '^ Exponentiation
    Debug.Print "Expon. "; x ^ y
    
    'Sqr square root
    Debug.Print "Sqr of y"; Sqr(x) 'Runtime Error 6: overflow

End Sub
```

Also, there seems to be s.th. weird with declaring and using Doubles:

```
Sub DoubleIssue()

    'Works
    Dim a
    a = 1.334
    Debug.Print TypeName(a) 'Prints Double
    
    'Breaks
    Dim b As Double
    b = 1.334 'Breaks here with overflow error

End Sub
```

I am on Mac/M1. It runs via parallels though.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is the full-stop after `Sqr(x)` a typo when copying to StackOverflow, or also present in the code you are running?

Comment: @Chronocidal typo in SO - fixed - thanks